# Estimate Causal Effect of Treatment on Binary Outcome

Tags: panel-data, binary-data, treatment-effect

I am a newbie with zero experience regarding the estimate of causal effects of treatment on binary outcome and this is my first post on stackexchange.

I have an unbalanced panel sample of about 5,000 individuals for **T=11** years (2008-2018). Min **t** for some individuals is **3**, max **t** is **11**. On average **t=6.5**.
I want to estimate the causal effect of temporary work on the probability of being employed.

The outcome variable **Y** is a binary variable that takes value one if the respondent is employed with a paid work in year **t** and zero otherwise (the respondent is not employed with a paid work in year **t**).

The treatment variable **T** is a binary variable that takes value one if the respondent is employed in a temporary work in year **t** and zero otherwise. This means that the treatment variable **T** will be equal to **0** if the respondent in year **t** belongs to one of the following categories:

- permanent employment
- part-time employment
- unemployment

If the respondent is unemployed in year **t**, both the treatment variable **T** and outcome **Y** are equal to **0** (**T=Y=0**).
If the respondent is a part-time employee in year **t**, then **T=0** and **Y==1**.
Similarly, if the respondent is a permanent employee in year **t**, then **T=0** and **Y==1**.
Finally, if the respondent is a temporary employee in year **t**, then **T=Y=1**.

A respondent who is unemployed in year **t** can move to permanent or part-time or temporary employment in year **t+1**.
A respondent who is a permanent or part-time employee in year **t** cannot move to temporary employment in year **t+1**. He/She can only move to unemployment if e.g., he/she get fired.
A part-time employee in year **t** can also move to permanent employment in year **t+1** (and vice versa).
A respondent who is a temporary employee in year **t** can move to unemployment or permanent or part-time employment in year **t+1**.

I begin my estimation using a Fixed Effects (FE) at the individual-level model, with **Y** being the outcome variable, **T** the main explanatory variable and some control variables (e.g., age and education of the respondent). To provide a causal estimation, I utilize [Lewbel’s (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1080/07350015.2012.643126) two-stage least squares (2SLS) approach.

Based on all the above, I would appreciate your opinion/feedback.
First of all, is the "coding" I have done correct? Does it make sense? Or it is something wrong...
Moreover, does my estimation strategy makes sense? Should I use an alternative approach?

Thank you all in advance!